# Save multiple checkbox cheked value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My checkbox value load from database "tbl_days". I want to store check-box checked value only which will store another db table.

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/settings/save_working_days" 
      method="post" onsubmit="return validateStandard(this)" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered"> 
<div class="form-group">
<?php
foreach ($working_days_info as $v_work) {
    ?>
<div class="input-group col-sm-1">
    <label  class="checkbox ">
            <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="day" style="width:20px;height: 18px;" />
            <span style="margin-left:5px;color: #000;font-size: 15px;"><?php echo $v_work->day ?></span>
    </label>
</div>
 <?php } ?>
       <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-1">
          <button type="submit" id="sbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>                            
       </div>           
</div>          
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of your checkbox from `name="day"` to `name="day[]"`, this way an array of checked values can be accessed through the `$_POST['day']` variable, then you can save them;

Accessing your Array in PHP would be `$_POST['day'][X];` where `X` is an index. using `var_dump($_POST['day']` will give you a clear view of what's inside the variable.